# ASP.NET MVC jQuery on IIS 6.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have big problem with deployment of asp.net mvc application on iis 6.0, i configured aspnet_isapi.dll, and the routing works fine, but json and jquery doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you configure your IIS6.0? (Did you use wildcard mappings?)

Answer (score 3):

You got firebug? check in the net tab if your scripts are getting downloaded, you may need to use `Html.ResolveUrl()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your routing probably works fine for the root directory of your site and Content folder. However, the routing through your isapi filter for your other folders may be wrong. Try moving the JavaScript files to the Content folder, to see if this is the problem.

You may not need this but just in case: http://biasecurities.com/blog/2008/how-to-enable-pretty-urls-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis6/